# Extracting value between m:properties tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the value of data placed between `m:properties` tag. How Can I do that?

```
<entry>
<id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7086)</id>
<title type="text"></title>
<updated>2018-04-25T02:39:22Z</updated>
<author>
  <name />
</author>
<link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7086)" />
<category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
<content type="application/xml">
  <m:properties>
    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">7086</d:Id>
    <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2018-04-24T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
    <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.7</d:BC_1MONTH>
    <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">1.87</d:BC_3MONTH>
    <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">2.05</d:BC_6MONTH>
    <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.25</d:BC_1YEAR>
    <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.48</d:BC_2YEAR>
    <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.63</d:BC_3YEAR>
    <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.83</d:BC_5YEAR>
    <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.95</d:BC_7YEAR>
    <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">3</d:BC_10YEAR>
    <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">3.08</d:BC_20YEAR>
    <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">3.18</d:BC_30YEAR>
    <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">3.18</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
  </m:properties>
</content>
```

I tried using request

```
r = requests.get('http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=month(NEW_DATE)%20eq%204%20and%20year(NEW_DATE)%20eq%202018')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
data = soup.find(id ='http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(7086)')
print(data)
```

Outputs is `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=month(NEW_DATE)%20eq%204%20and%20year(NEW_DATE)%20eq%202018')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
data = soup.find_all("content")
for i in data:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. How do I extract if I have multiple m:properties? I want to extract 10 years US bond yield from this link http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=month(NEW_DATE)%20eq%204%20and%20year(NEW_DATE)%20eq%202018

Comment: Updated snippet. You can use `soup.find_all("content")`

Comment: I need to get content of this <d:id m:type="Edm.Int32">7086</d:id>. That has latest bond yield. Sorry for bothering, I am new to this.

Comment: `data[0].find("m:properties").find("d:id").text` should get you what you want